# How properly drop database in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I created a script to drop and recreate database in postgresql

```
     conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host=replica_db_host,
            user=replica_db_user,
            password=replica_db_password,
            dbname=replica_db_name
        )
        conn.autocommit = True
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Terminate connections and recreate the database
        cursor.execute(
            f"SELECT pg_terminate_backend (pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = '{replica_db_name}';")  # noqa
        cursor.execute(f"DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {replica_db_name}")
        cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {replica_db_name}")

        # Close the connection
        conn.close()
```

Got error

```
      SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

How to properly drop and recreate a database if its still open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'oh. The connection was closed quite expectedly, because you were connected to the database when you closed all connections to the database. Connect to a different database if you want to drop a database. The database `postgres` is designed for this very purpose.

Comment: That's a different, unrelated question.